# Does inline function and Fzero can be used to solve nonlinear equations in which other parameters entered are user defined?

Tags: matlab, inline

I want to solve an equation in `matlab` for value Ql for this I have given command:

```
f=inline('Ql^2 + Ql/(1+x((Q4*Ql)/(Q4+Ql))+ y)*(x +(x*(1+z)/(Q4*Ql)^2)
/(1+(x*Q4*Ql*z)/((Q4+Ql)*(1+y)+ x*Q4*Ql)))');
  g = fzero(f,0);
```

where Q4 is computed based on parameters taken from user and x y z are direct inputs from user, my problem is that when I use this I get error:

???Error using ==> fzero at 301
FZERO cannot continue because user supplied inline `object ==> f`
failed with the error below.

> Not enough inputs to inline function.

But I am sure that I am entering every value required.
Is it that inline functions always work with constants and not user defined functions, if so what should I use to solve this equation for Ql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. First, `inline` is deprecated. Use an anonymous function instead:

```
f = @(Ql) (Ql^2 + Ql/(1+x((Q4*Ql)/(Q4+Ql))+ y)*(x +(x*(1+z)/(Q4*Ql)^2) /(1+(x*Q4*Ql*z)/((Q4+Ql)*(1+y)+ x*Q4*Ql))));
```

Second, the part `x((Q4*Ql)/(Q4+Ql))` treats `x` as an array or a function. I assume what you want here is to multiply `x` with the expression in parentheses:

```
f = @(Ql) (Ql^2 + Ql/(1+x*((Q4*Ql)/(Q4+Ql))+ y)*(x +(x*(1+z)/(Q4*Ql)^2) /(1+(x*Q4*Ql*z)/((Q4+Ql)*(1+y)+ x*Q4*Ql))));
```

Third, the function may not be defined at the point of your initial guess, 0. To test the code I used the values `x = 1; y = 2; z = 3; Q4 = 4;`, and for these, `f(0)` is NaN. Make sure this doesn't happen with your actual parameters.

If everything is in order, this code should do the trick:

```
f = @(Ql) (Ql^2 + Ql/(1+x*((Q4*Ql)/(Q4+Ql))+ y)*(x +(x*(1+z)/(Q4*Ql)^2) /(1+(x*Q4*Ql*z)/((Q4+Ql)*(1+y)+ x*Q4*Ql))));
g = fzero(f, 0);
```